# Обновление базы по истечении времени

Tags: php, sql

Доброго времени суток.

Есть таблица в  БД. Нужно обновлять ее раз в два часа. Записываем время в таблицу, в php вытаскиваем текущее время и сравниваем и если результат подходит по условиям, то UPDATE, не  так нет. Вопрос: как сравнить две даты? Формат, к примеру, (`10:21:32 /hh:mm:ss`).

Comment: а чем cron не подходит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [strtotime()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.strtotime.php) и сравнивайте разницу между датами например с [time()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.time.php)

Answer (score 1):

Если вы храните данные в таблице, то используйте тип даты/времени, например, datetime.
Тогда посчитать интервал времени между двумя датами можно с помощью функции [TIMESTAMPDIFF](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_datediff_function/page2.html) (мне почему-то показалось, что вы используете MySQL).